# Transport Layer Security boost sockets

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, transport-security

Does anyone know how to implement tls using boost sockets ? I have implemented ssl but I would not mind extending it to tls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssl::context_base` class [already supports](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context_base/method.html) TLS:

> **ssl::context_base::method**
>
> Different methods supported by a context.

you'll want to use `ssl::context_base::method::tlsv1`